# If $x= \cos B+i\sin B$ and $1+\sqrt{1-a^2}=na$ then prove that $1+a\cos B=(a/2n)(1+nx)(1+n/x)$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $x= \cos B+i\sin B$ and $1+\sqrt{1-a^2}=na$ then prove that $1+a\cos B=(a/2n)(1+nx)(1+n/x)$

I know homeworks aren't allowed but at least give me a hint where to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As $2n=a(n^2+1),\dfrac a{2n}=?, \dfrac n{n^2+1}=?$

$$x+\dfrac1x=2\cos B$$

Comment: How do I get $a$ into the last equation?

Comment: @Shoaib, Replace $n/n^2+1$ with $a/2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $n=\tan y$

$\implies a=\dfrac{2n}{n^2+1}=\sin2y$

$nx=e^{iB}\tan y,\dfrac nx=e^{-iB}\tan y$

Comment: After adding the last two equations I got 2cosB * tan y. On squaring both sides  I got x^2 + 1/x^2 + 2= 4(cosB)^2